# AngularJS - routing doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am learning angular js for a project i'm building.

So far it seems like a great framework, very helpful and intuitive,
but i am having problems whenever i try to implement routing...

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController'
            }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

        });

        app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.people = [

                {
                    name: "Arik",
                    age: 19
                },

                {
                    name: "Bar",
                    age: 19
                }

            ];

        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and home.html:

```
<ul>

    <li data-ng-repeat="person in people">
        <b>{{ person.name }}</b> - {{ person.age }}
    </li>

</ul>
```

The problem is that it just doesn't work, the page shows blank.
I tried searching in the official documentation but nothing helped...

What am i doing wrong?

By the way, i am using the latest version, 1.4.4

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Also look at the network tab of the dev tools. Any 404 error (for a script, or for the home.html page)?

Comment: Many, XMLHttpRequest cannot load, Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load, Error: [$compile:tpload]

Comment: You actually have a web server to serve your files and a URL like `http://.../index.html` in the browser address bar, right? Because if you just open the index.html file from the file system (and thus have an URL like `file://...`), the browser won't do any AJAX request, for security reasons.

Comment: FYI regarding that error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload. Sounds like @JBNizet's comment is the most likely problem. If you are running a web server, you need to make sure you're using the correct path for your template URL.

Comment: I have just tried to run the project from visual studio and it works!! I feel like an idiot...
What can i do to run the project properly from the file system? I don't want to always rely on visual studio.

Comment: You just can't use the file system. But you don't need Visual Studio either. Just any web server able to serve static files. If you use NodeJS, use the http-server npm package, for example. You start it from the command-line, and it justs serves all the files from the current directory and subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lohiux?p=preview) and works fine, probably the issue is in your path to `home.html` or your web server or something similar, look at your environment.

Try out [`grunt-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) to create a web server while you are developing, it's very helpful

Also i recommend you to use [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), is much more simple. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/USKmnn?p=info) is a working template for routing with ui-router in plunker

Comment: Thank you, as JBNizet pointed out, the problem was that i tried running the project from the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks great, and the prove is that it works [take a look at this](http://embed.plnkr.co/ZLwtKnxsrKi6ArrKwvAH/preview),
I would recommend you to load the scripts after the html, so you don't keep the user looking at a blank page till the file is downloaded.